# JQuery - which form was submitted?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a page of products and for each of them, I want to have a form that uses AJAX to update the session.  I've done this bit - just providing background.

I use the product's ID to create a different form class and name for each form, so each form is called something like `this_form_name_567` and the next would be `this_form_name_568` and so on.

There is a submit button per form.  I'm having trouble figuring out

1. Which event is best to use so that the correct form will be identified when a submit button is clicked?
2. Once clicked, how to then make sure the correct value is taken from a hidden field (unique ID) within the submitted form so that I can populate a line of code such as:

   ```
   $.post("compare_response.php", {compare_this: $("#compare_this").val()}, function(data){
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) tree traversal method to get the form in which the button of interest is nested:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest("form").attr("id"));
});
```

or even simpler, just get the element's `form` property :)

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    alert(this.form.id);
});
```

[**You can try it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/CRXuV/)

Comment: I suppose the submit button is inside the form. you can also use `.parents("form")`

Comment: Thanks very much everyone - I didn't need anything quite so clever for the hidden field, but very good to know.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the form you are submitting like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var yourForm = $(this);
    var hiddenValue = $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val();
});
```

Of course you can get the hidden value differently, or if you have more than one hidden you'll have to give a little more information about it.